# Sequelize JS how to handle validations

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, discord.js

I'm using Sequelize in my Bot for Discord in NodeJS.

SO in a modal (table) definition i need to put, to an Integer column the max and min value. I see in the Sequelize wiki that is only

```
validate: {min: 0, max:100}
```

So now however i need to modify them via command and handle when something happen and go more 100 or less 0, to retrieve a reply.

For the first I see that doing `model.updateAttributes();` and then modify the max or the min or both, can update them without force syncing the model (table) (I think...)

But for the second? How can I handle when, for exaemple it goes under 0 or up to 100? I see tat is there the `Sequelize.validationError`, that is a part of `Sequelize.uniqueConstraintError`, but searching and trying I haven't found how to handle these.

How can I do it? If it is possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you seeking for, let me know ?

```
validate : {
    max : {
     args: 100,
      msg: "YOUR ERROR OR WARNING MESSAGE HERE."
    },
    min : {
    args: 0,
      msg: "YOUR ERROR OR WARNING MESSAGE HERE."
    }
```

Comment: Yes i think, for the model, but from the code how can i handle? If i put a value that is more or less, it return me the catch error (i put the model.update in a try catch), not the msg i put in the model

Comment: Note that 0 evaluates to false.  [0] to use a numeric value.